# C++ regex - First group should be optional

Tags: c++, regex, c++20

I have the following C++ code to parse a C++ code in a string:

```
std::string cpp_code = "  static int foo(int a, float b)\n{\n/* here could be your code */\n}\n";
std::string function_regex_str = R"(\s*(\w+)?\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\((.*)\)\s+\{\s+(.*)\s+\})";
std::regex function_regex(function_regex_str, std::regex::ECMAScript);
    
std::cmatch sm;
auto ret = std::regex_search(cpp_code.c_str(), sm, function_regex);
if (ret) {
   std::cout << "fbound:\t" << sm[1] << std::endl;
   std::cout << "ftype:\t" << sm[2] << std::endl;
   std::cout << "fname:\t" << sm[3] << std::endl;
   std::cout << "fparam:\t" << sm[4] << std::endl;
   std::cout << "fbody:\t" << sm[5] << std::en)dl;
}
```

The code works fine. Now the first group (`sm[1]`) should be optional. So I appended `?` to the first group `(\w+)`. But if I tested the code with the shorten string

`cpp_code = "int foo(int a, float b)\n{\n/* here could be your code */\n}\n"`

regex_search returns false.

- How can I make the first group (in the code above for the substring `static`) optional?

I tested the code with Visual Studio 2022 C++.

Comment: The regex expects "spaces_opt word_opt **spaces** word **spaces** word paren more...", but you are passing "no_spaces word space word paren".  It seems to me the real problem is you are trying to use regex as a grammar parser.  Except for the simplest of cases, that will lead to a lot of tears.  Boost [Spirit X3](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/index.html) might be a better option.

Comment: The regex requires spaces at the start of the line - but you don't have any.  Instead of `R"(\s*(\w+)?\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\((.*)\)\s+\{\s+(.*)\s+\})"` you should use `R"(\s*(?:(\w+)\s+)?(\w+)\s+(\w+)\((.*)\)\s+\{\s+(.*)\s+\})` to make the required spaces following the first word also optional https://regex101.com/r/pJw4O8/1

Comment: You have a problem.  You say "I know, I'll use regex!".  You now have two problems; the original problem, and a regex to write and understand